# How to verify series solution to an ode generated by AsymptoticDSolveValue?

Tags: differential-equations, series-expansion, testing-and-verification

To verify solution returned by `DSolve`, one can use the method shown in
[howto/CheckTheResultsOfDSolve.html](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CheckTheResultsOfDSolve.html)  and look for `True` (may be after a `Simplify`

---

[image]

---

But how to verify the solution from `AsymptoticDSolveValue`?  Trying to do something similar to the above will not work, since simple substitution would not work because the solution is now a truncated series and so one will not get an exact zero on the left side.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ode = x^2*(-x^2 + 2)*y''[x] - x*(4*x^2 + 3)*y'[x] + (-2*x^2 + 2)*y[x] == 0;
sol = AsymptoticDSolveValue[ode, y[x], {x, 0, 8}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now

```
sol2 = y -> Function[{x}, Evaluate[sol]]
```

[image]

And now

```
 Simplify[ode /. sol2]
```

Does not give `True` (understandably) , it gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I think Mathematica needs a specialized function for verification of solution of `DSolve` and `AsymptoticDSolveValue`. Maple has such a function called `odetest` which works for standard solution and series solution

```
restart;
ode:=x^2*(-x^2+2)*diff(diff(y(x),x),x)-x*(4*x^2+3)*diff(y(x),x)+(-2*x^2+2)*y(x) = 0;
Order:=9;
sol:=dsolve(ode,y(x),series,x=0);
```

[image]

To verify the above, one can do

```
 odetest(sol,ode,series,x=0)
                    
              0
```

And look for zero as result. If the result is not zero, then it did not verify the solution.

Is there something in Mathematica that can be used to verify result of `AsymptoticDSolveValue`? For example, one can obtain a series solution in some other way, and want to use Mathematica to verify this solution against the ODE. How to do this?

V 12.3.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps `Asymptotic` helps:

```
Asymptotic[ode /. sol2,x->0]
(* True*)
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about the function Asymptotic.